# Duplicated tags: should "deletion" and "securedelete" be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Topics tagged [deletion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletion) (46 questions) and [securedelete](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/securedelete) (only 7 questions, some even having both tags...) seem to cover similar domains: how to delete disks, files, VM, DB entries, etc.

Shouldn't [securedelete](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/securedelete) be merged into [deletion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletion) or linked as synonyms?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Considering that we are on *security*.se, almost any tag that has "security" or "secure" in its name will be a false flag. (Well, there are a few exceptions: mod-security, security-theater...)

Comment: And, for that matter, is [tag:destruction] different from [tag:deletion]? Cc @AviD

Comment: @Gilles a quick glance looks like the destruction tag is more about physical destruction, but then again this is still the same purpose from our perspective... so I'm not sure.

Comment: @AviD [Let's see what others think](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/are-deletion-and-destruction-synonyms)

Answer (score 8):

On another SE, I would say "no".  But on Information Security, I think the answer is "yes".

The notion of "deleting information", in a security context, implies - or should imply - securely deleting that information.